# Joomla Menu and sub menus

Tags: menu, joomla, submenu, heading

I want to display first level of main menu under Joomla. For eg. I have menu something like this

- Heading1

  - Sub-menu1
  - Sub-menu2
  - Sub-menu3
- Heading2
- Heading3

I want to display just Heading1, Heading2, and Heading3 not Sub-menu1,Sub-menu2, and Sub-menu3.

Any help will be appreciated. I've tried using end level and start level but nothing seems to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using joomla default menu module then

set start level to 0 and end level to 1
menu style should be "list" or "legacy vertical".

Comment: How can I show the submenus only. I don't want the parent menus. Please advise...

Comment: If you want only submenus then you can set start level to 1 and end level to any big number. and if you want only. Or if you want menu items of any particular level then set start and end level same.

Comment: @Anand could you enlighten, where could I find the named parameters here 'Start Level' and 'End Level'
I am a newbie on Joomla

Comment: you can find these fields in parameters of joomla's menu module